# I'm extending User model in django and I'm not able to authenticate because of raw password

Tags: django, django-authentication

So the problem is I have extended User model in django. and I have written views for it. 
Here is my models code :-

```
class StudentProfile(User):
    batch = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

here is my auth backend file :-

from quizapp.models import StudentProfile

```
class StudentAuthenticationBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            student = StudentProfile.objects.get(username=username)
            if student.check_password(password):
                return student
        except StudentProfile.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return StudentProfile.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except StudentProfile.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

And I have made changes in seetings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'quizapp.backends.StudentAuthenticationBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

I'm printing username,password and authentication user. This is what i got :-

When using django created superuser

```
>> a = authenticate(username="super",password="super")
>> print(a)
>> super
```

But when using user created by form,

```
>> b = authenticate(username="test",password="123")
>> print(b)
>> None
```

I have cross checked username and password and it's true.
So but in auth_user table, username is super and password is encrypted but for test user, username is user and password is 123.

So the problem must be django is taking 123 is encrypted password and using decrypted version of it to authenticate.

Is there any way to solve this?

I have used OneToOneField and added extra fields in StudentProfile model. Now I'm using forms and registering user with it.

This is the view code :-

```
def register_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = StudentProfile.objects.create(
                  username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                  password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
                  batch=form.cleaned_data['batch'],
                  first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
                  last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
                  course=form.cleaned_data['course'],
                  date_of_birth=form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth'],
                  secret_question=form.cleaned_data['secret_question'],
                  answer=form.cleaned_data['answer'],
                  contact=form.cleaned_data['contact']
                 )
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
   else:
       form = RegistrationForm()

     variables = RequestContext(request, {'form': form})
     return render_to_response('registration/register.html',variables)
```

And I'm getting IntegrityError at /register/
null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint error. 
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Is `Student.check_password` a function you wrote, or is it using the method from `User`?  How are you setting the password? Are you using `Student.set_password?`?

Comment: Yes it does. I've done it in dozens of projects from django 1.1 to 1.4. I know that some people suggest against it (for good reason) but I have found it works excellently for me. You don't need to write a auth backend if you're just subclassing User. (In response to a deleted comment- you can't subclass User)

Answer (score 2):

From the Django authenication docs section on [storing additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users):

> If you'd like to store additional information related to your users, Django provides a method to specify a site-specific related model -- termed a "user profile" -- for this purpose.
>
> To make use of this feature, define a model with fields for the additional information you'd like to store, or additional methods you'd like to have available, and also add a `OneToOneField` named `user` from your model to the `User` model. This will ensure only one instance of your model can be created for each `User`.

So you shouldn't subclass `User` at all -- that's the root of your problem. Instead, you should create another model with a one-to-one relationship with `User` and add your fields there.

Comment: I'm following this, new way, http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/
So there must be a way to fix this.

Comment: @Jainit That feature was abandoned. It never made it into a stable version of Django and if you follow the link from that post to [the docs for the feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#model-inheritance) you'll see the section no longer exists even in the `dev` version. You need to use a "user profile".

Comment: Now I'm using OneToOneField and I'm getting new errors, I have edited the question

Comment: @Jainit I don't really understand your edit. You should be creating two models -- one normal `User` with `username`, etc. and another `StudentProfile` with `user = the_user_object_you_just_created` and `answer`, `contact`, etc.

Comment: Can you just give me link to the exaple, This is what I'm doing, http://pastebin.com/1MRKhaxE

Comment: @Jainit `StudentProfile` shouldn't subclass `User` just `models.Model` and it should have a `user` field that is a `models.OneToOneField(User)`. Follow the link in my answer for the full docs. You need to set `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'my_app_name.StudentProfile'` in your `settings.py`